# Add to array for every 60 counted from 1000+ results in javascript

Tags: javascript

What I'm trying to do is create a page for every 60 results found. Meaning if I'm given a number

`1,390` results
For every **60** of those results, add to array. Meaning, the results array will hold page numbers.

Expected result array:

`results = [1,2,3,4,5...]`

I'm trying to go for the best memory saving tactic, but maybe it seems a loop is most appropriate?

```
results = [];
for (var i = 0, res = 0; i < total; i + 60, res++) {
    results.push(res);
}
// this just causes browser to crash
```

How can I add a result to the result array for every 60 results?

Comment: `i + 60` doesn’t do anything. It needs to be `i += 60`.

Comment: `i + 60` should be `i += 60`. i + 60 always evaluates to 60, which is always less than total, and it will loop forever.

Comment: Doh'. Awesome thanks for the help

Comment: Add a condition `if !(res % 60)  results.push(res)`.

Comment: @K.Daniek Ah i see. I didn't want to go that route. I just wanted to have 60 results per page. And maybe show 8 pages at a time. But that's a good tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var total = 1390;
var numPages = Math.ceil(total / 60);
var results = [];
for (i = 1; i <= numPages; i++) {
    results.push(i);
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(results));
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use a simple filter function

```
results = results.filter(function(item,index){
  return index % 60 === 0;
});
```

this would return every item in results that has a index divisible by 60;